# Installing an unauthorized wifi card in a Lenovo thinkpad edge 14

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, hardware, hardware-compatibility

I took out a my Intel dual band Wireless AC 7260 card model number 7260HMW from another laptop. I wanted to install it in my thinkpad. Upon doing so and rebooting, the computer said unauthorized wifi card and I need to remove it. I read that Lenovo does this to force the use of IBM wifi cards. I am currently running Ubunut 14.04 and I know it has native support for this card whereas 13 did not. Is there a way to get around bios reading the wifi card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you're willing to replace the BIOS. IBMs are usually considered "corporate" machines and this restriction is a "feature" so that you as a user can not install an unsecured or untested Wi-Fi card and bring down your corporate network.

Even in the "home" space, it is still considered a "security feature". This is a design decision by IBM and there's not going to be a good way around it. Your best bet is to replace the computer or buy a supported Wi-Fi card.

Also, keep in mind that some platforms (There is an Intel-based one that I can't remember at the moment) are based on CPU, Wi-Fi, and GPU all working together in unison to achieve "better" battery life v.s. performance. If your system is using a platform like this it may not be able to run a Wi-Fi card that does not conform.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your BIOS or the ID of your card. See the [Problem with unauthorized MiniPCI network card](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card) article on the ThinkWiki for details.